# jquery selector for child element

Tags: jquery-selectors

What is the correct method for looping through the lowest level "li" elements?

```
<div id="mainnav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <!-- These are the elements I want to loop through -->
                <li>
                </li>
                <li>
                </li>
                <li>
                </li>
                <!-- End These are the elements I want to loop through -->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried this but the selector is not firing.

```
jQuery("#mainNav > ul > li > ul > li").each(function () { 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[#ID selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) are case sensitive, you need `#mainnav` (lower case `n`), like this:

```
jQuery("#mainnav > ul > li > ul > li").each(function () { 

});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3mBtP/).

Comment: Didn't notice the case difference. I'm building on someone else's work so by habit I used my normal casing....Cheers!